# Share ZedGraphControl between two forms

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I have the following problem/task:

I have a Zedgraph in Form1. That zedgraph gets updated within Form1. Now I would like to have the option to un-dock that graph into a new form (Form2). Form1 would now have to be able to update the zedgraph in form2. Furthermore, the zedgraph should return to the original form (form1) after I close form2.

How could anything like that be done? Is it possible? Any hints?

Comment: is the zedgraph an object? If it is you can just pass it to the other form as a property

Comment: yes, it is an object. but if i pass it to the second form it disappears in the first form.. which would not be to bad, but how do i manage to return the object and display it again in the first form after the second form gets closed? (did i mention that i am pretty new to c#? :/ )

Answer (score 0):

Just create two zed graph one for main form one for other form. Zedgraph has a sequence to plot data. you can copy it's data and plot on second form. And after doing this you can hide zedgraph on main form.